# Retaining UI state after onBackPressed()

Tags: android

I implemented a broadcast receiver to update one of my UI activities but my problem is this: when the back button is pressed by the user, android kills the broadcast receiver but when the home button is clicked, the state is retained. What am trying to achieve is retaining the state even after the back buttton is clicked-- `onBackPressed()` until the user explicitly calls `finish()`. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you call unregisterReceiver() from onBackPressed() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your receiver in your `onCreate()` method and call `unregisterReceiver()` on `onDestroy()`.

**Edit:**

You can see @Shiki's answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/2015538).
It does what you need.

Comment: This seems to solve my issue by the looks of things tnx.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on your `Activity` being always accessible to receive the broadcast. Instead, use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to attempt to deliver the broadcast to the `Activity`, and if it fails - store the update locally and apply it when the `Activity` is displayed next time.